# Javascript background changing based on function

Tags: javascript, button, random, background, click

I have to simulate a function that chooses random numbers between 0 and 37 when I click a button. If it's even, the background is red. If it's odd, the background is black. The initial background is light blue. This is what I have so far, and it is not working.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Wheel</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var currentNum = wheelspins();
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#00ffff";

function wheelspins()
{
return Math.floor(Math.random() * 37);

if(currentNum % 2 == 0){
style.backgroundColor="#FF0000";
}
else if(currentNum %2 == 1){
style.backgroundColor="#000000";
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>

<input type="text" name="Number" value="" id="wheelspins()" size="10"/>
<input type="button" value="Spin Wheel" onclick="document.getElementById('wheelspins()').value=wheelspins();"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 'it is not working' is not a useful problem statement.

Answer (score 1):

I see two possible issues.  First, the evaluation code never gets run because the function returns before the background can be changed.  Second, you should write `document.body.style.background` instead of `style.background` in the function.  Change your `wheelspins()` function to be like this and it should work:

```
function wheelspins()
{
  //If you return here, then the rest of the function won't get run
  currentNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 37);

  if(currentNum % 2 == 0){
    document.body.style.backgroundColor="#FF0000";
  }
  else if(currentNum %2 == 1){
    document.body.style.backgroundColor="#000000";
  }
  return currentNum
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few issues with your javascript.. for example the `if-else` block of your `wheelspins` function is never reached as you are returning the random number (maybe you are missing a bracket?)

Also, it's unclear what you are trying to accomplish with your `<input type="text" />` html. Do you want the random number generated returned there?

You also only need to evaluate whether your number is even (or odd). Here's an example:

```js
function wheelSpin(){
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 37);
    if(random % 2 == 0){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
    } else {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
    }
}
```

```css
body{
    background-color: #00ffff;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="wheelSpin()">Spin Wheel</button>
```